# iOS swift how to place an imageview in a uiview exactly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have an issue, I'm creating an imageView programmatically and then add it to a center view, which is kind of working. But the problem is that is not taking the whole space in the center view, it appears yes in the uiview but not covering all always a bit down. Any help?

The code:

```
//let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: centerView.frame)
            let backgroundImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.centerView.bounds.size.width, height: self.centerView.bounds.size.height))
            print("backgorundImage coordinates: \(backgroundImage.frame)")
            backgroundImage.image = drawOverImage
            backgroundImage.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(centerView.bounds.width, self.centerView.bounds.height))
            //check this the image is being drawn bottom because is the fame for the previous 0.0
            //backgroundImage.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(ALEdge.Top, relation: NSLayoutRelation.Equal)
            //backgroundImage.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill //too big
            //backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit     //sama
            backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
            //imageView.image = background
            backgroundImage.center = view.center

            let coordinatesForImage: CGRect = self.view.convertRect(backgroundImage.frame, toView: centerView)
            let pointOfImage: CGPoint = backgroundImage.convertPoint(self.centerView.frame.origin, toView: backgroundImage)

            print("coordinates test: \(coordinatesForImage)")
            print("point x: \(pointOfImage.x)")
            print("point y: \(pointOfImage.y)")

            //backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
            self.centerView.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)


            let pointOfImageToSuperView: CGPoint = (backgroundImage.superview?.convertPoint(backgroundImage.center, toView: self.centerView))!

            print("superview imagepoint: \(pointOfImageToSuperView)")
```

The comments are all the thing I'm trying to do.

EDIT: 
This is what is happening.

[image: Missing bottom]

I missing a little bit from the bottom, now I don't know if is the size of the image or what, could i change the size of the uiview to match the image?

Comment: You are doing a WHOLE bunch of frame manipulation there...  If you want it to cover, exactly, the superview (`centerView`) all you need to do is set the frame like you do in the first line.  Don't do `sizeThatFits`.  Don't do `*.center = *.center`.  Don't do point or rect conversion from one view to the other.  Etc...  Your first line tells the view "Be exactly as big as this other view and start at (0,0)".  Then add it as a subview and it will be perfectly oriented inside it's parent (`centerView`).

Comment: Well I have it like I wanted it, but is there a way to tell the centerView I want you as big as the image after is in you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try:

```
let backgroundImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.centerView.bounds)
backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
backgroundImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
self.centerView.addSubview(backgroundImage)
```

Comment: Yep that did it, but the image does not cover the whole area, it is missing a bit down. I don't know why, do you?

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso Try editing the `contentMode` property of the `UIImageView`. Updated answer.